# Measuring test generation time in Pex

Tags: c#, .net, pex, intellitest

I would like to measure the time that Pex takes in generating unit tests for a specific C# function. How I can get such information?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? The time taken to generate tests will depend on how long you let IntelliTest/Pex have a go at the code. I mean for complex code (with deep loops/recursion, etc.), you can keep tweaking the various bounds to let to explorer deeper and deeper. So I am not sure what you are trying to measure. Hence I ask.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to compare the time taken by Pex to generate tests against another dynamic symbolic execution based tool.

Answer (score 0):

We do not expose any means (like an API, etc.) that reports the time taken by IntelliTest to generate tests. As I mentioned earlier the time taken to generate tests can depend on various factors.
Incidentally, folks at the Budapest University of Technology and Economics have some interesting data that compares test generators (including IntelliTest) that you might find relevant. Please see here: https://github.com/SETTE-Testing/sette-tool/wiki